# Why are my images truncated when cursor is hover it after a scale (1.5) effect?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

We have an online courses platform. We use Wordpress 5 with Eduma theme and Learnpress plugin.

I am trying to make a netflix effect on the thumbnails of my courses.

I successfully did it but on the first row of courses, the image is truncated.

[image]

I tried to make a minimum code to reproduce the issue and paste it here, but there are too many css coming from the theme and different plugins. Impossible to leave some minimum code.

You can see the issue on the homepage of `https://formatine.com/` in the rows of courses. Pass the cursor hover a course and you will see the zoom effect.

The second row is fine, but the first row has the issue.

I tried to change the css of parent container because I thought something nested is cutting the effect.
I tried some z-index on different divs, but it didn't work.

After days of investigation, I came here to see if anyone has an idea of what I am doing wrong.

Please help.

Comment: It’s because `.thim-course-grid` has `overflow: hidden` applied.

Comment: Yeah, same as I found also, now the images won't truncate. But on hover, the elements in the second row also getting moved back and forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the research, what I was able to find was:

There is one `overflow: hidden` applied to one of the parent div with class name as `thim-course-grid`.

Removing it will solve the issue.

Can you check and update?